# Angular 2 ngModel mutator directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I would like to build a directive that can mutate values being passed to and from an input, bound with ngModel.

Say I wanted to do a date mutation, every time the model changes, the mutator first gets to change the value to the proper format (eg "2017-05-03 00:00:00" is shown as "2017/05/03"), before ngModel updates the view. When the view changes, the mutator gets to change the value before ngModel updates the model (eg entering "2017/08/03" sets the model to "2017-08-03 00:00:00" [timestamp]).

The directive would be used like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="someModel" mutate="date:YYYY/MM/DD" />
```

My first instinct was to get a reference to the ControlValueAccessor and NgModel on the Host component.

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, 
         Host, OnChanges, Optional, Self, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel, ControlValueAccessor, 
         NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';


@Directive({ 
    selector: '[mutate]',
})
export class MutateDirective {

    constructor(
        @Host() private _ngModel: NgModel, 
        @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) 
            private _controlValueAccessor: ControlValueAccessor[]
    ){
        console.log('mutute construct', _controlValueAccessor);
    }


}
```

Then I realized that the Angular 2 Forms classes are complicated and I have no idea what I'm doing. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Based on the answer below I came up with the solution: [see gist](https://gist.github.com/christiaan-lombard/31c5e3ccbd55f9ce523d64f9bf48b5f5)

Usage (requires Moment JS):

```
<input  mutate="YYYY/MM/DD" inputFormat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" [(ngModel)]="someDate">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you need to implement ControlValueAccessor in some class and provide it as a NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR for the ngModel with some directive. This ControlValueAccessor and directive can actually be the same class.

TL;DR
It's not very obvious but still not very complicated. Below is the skeleton from one of my date controls. This thing acts as a parser/formatter pair for the angular 1 ng-model.

It all starts with ngModel injecting all NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR's into itself. There are bunch of default providers as well, and they all get injected into ngModel constructor, but ngModel can distinguish between default value accessors and the ones provided by the user. So it picks one to work with. Roughly it looks like this: if there's user's value accessor then it will be picked, otherwise it falls back to choosing from default ones. After that initial setup is done.

Control value accessor should subscribe to the 'input' or some other similar event on input element to process input events from it.

When value is changed externally ngModel calls writeValue() method on value accessor picked during initialization. This method is responsible for rendering display value that will go into an input as string shown to user.

At some point (usually on blur event) control can be marked as touched. This is shown as well.

Please note: code below is not real production code, it has not been tested, it can contain some discrepancies or inaccuracies, but in general it shows the whole idea of this approach.

```
import {
    Directive,
    Input,
    Output,
    SimpleChanges,
    ElementRef,
    Renderer,
    EventEmitter,
    OnInit,
    OnDestroy,
    OnChanges,
    forwardRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription, Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from '@angular/forms';

const DATE_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR_PROVIDER = [
    {provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateInputDirective), multi: true}
];

@Directive({
    // [date-input] is just to distinguish where exactly to place this control value accessor
    selector: 'input[date-input]',
    providers: [DATE_INPUT_VALUE_ACCESSOR_PROVIDER],
    host: { 'blur': 'onBlur()', 'input': 'onChange($event)' }
})
export class DateInputDirective implements ControlValueAccessor, OnChanges {

    @Input('date-input')
    format: string;

    model: TimeSpan;

    private _onChange: (value: Date) => void = () => {
    };

    private _onTouched: () => void = () => {
    };

    constructor(private _renderer: Renderer,
                private _elementRef: ElementRef,
                // something that knows how to parse value
                private _parser: DateParseTranslator,
                // something that knows how to format it back into string
                private _formatter: DateFormatPipe) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes['format']) {
            this.updateText(this.model, true);
        }
    }

    onBlur = () => {
        this.updateText(this.model, false);
        this.onTouched();
    };

    onChange = ($event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        // the value of an input - don't remember exactly where it is in the event
        // so this part may be incorrect, please check
        let value = $event.target.value;
        let date = this._parser.translate(value);
        this._onChange(date);
    };

    onTouched = () => {
        this._onTouched();
    };

    registerOnChange = (fn: (value: Date) => void): void => {
        this._onChange = fn;
    };

    registerOnTouched = (fn: () => void): void => {
        this._onTouched = fn;
    };

    writeValue = (value: Date): void => {
        this.model = value;
        this.updateText(value, true);
    };

    updateText = (date: Date, forceUpdate = false) => {
        let textValue = date ? this._formatter.transform(date, this.format) : '';
        if ((!date || !textValue) && !forceUpdate) {
            return;
        }
        this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', textValue);
    }

}
```

Then in the html template:

```
<input date-input="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myModel"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works a treat. I was hoping not to have to deal with the specific input element (`event.target.value`) so it could be compatible with any type of input supported by ngModel. Maybe by grabbing the existing default ControlValueAccessor and wrapping it before it is provided to NgModel.  Based on your code I came up with this for mutating dates, [GIST](https://gist.github.com/christiaan-lombard/31c5e3ccbd55f9ce523d64f9bf48b5f5)

Comment: You can't do that. If you look at ng2 sources you'll see that they do the same thing - they just have bunch of value accessors for different types of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anything with Forms here. As an example, I made a credit card masking directive that formats the user input into a credit card string (a space every 4 characters, basically).

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[credit-card]' // Attribute selector
})
export class CreditCard {

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  confirmFirst(event: any) {
    let val = event.target.value;
    event.target.value = this.setElement(val);
  }

  constructor(public element: ElementRef) { }

  setElement(val) {
    let num = '';
    var v = val.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
    var matches = v.match(/\d{4,16}/g);
    var match = matches && matches[0] || '';
    var parts = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = match.length; i < len; i += 4) {
      parts.push(match.substring(i, i + 4));
    }
    if (parts.length) {
      num = parts.join(' ').trim();
    } else {
      num = val.trim();
    }
    return num;
  }

}
```

Then I used it in a template like so:

```
<input credit-card type="text" formControlName="cardNo" />
```

I am using form control in this example, but it doesnt matter either way. It should work fine with ngModel binding.